Kubernetes namespace "aks-command"
I recently noticed a new namespace on my AKS cluster called “aks-command”. I have not created this namespace and I suspect that AKS did.
To check if this namespace was created by AKS (or by a user), I tried to check the logs, but it is not possible to see logs older than 90 days.
I would like to know:

Is this a new initial namespace like the ones created by Kubernetes (default, kube-system, etc) ?
If yes, what is it for and what happens if I delete it?

Thanks in advance


Is this a new initial namespace like the ones created by Kubernetes (default, kube-system, etc) ?

"aks-command" namespace is created by aks service when someone executed aks command invole against your cluster. See here for more details.

If yes, what is it for and what happens if I delete it?

The invoked command will be carry out by pod running in this "aks-command" namespace. You can delete the namespace but it will be automatically created again during next invoke command.
